# Could static electricity from trading card binder pages damage SMD components?

Tags: surface-mount, esd, storage, static-electricity

I bought a trading card binder to hold SMD components.  I chose it because its card-sized sleeves can hold more than just tape strips and also it has a zipper.   However my concern is that the clear plastic sleeves generate a little static and I am wondering if it could damage components.  The binder would contain resistors, capacitors, LEDs, diodes, MOSFETs, different ICs including MCUs, and random SMD jacks and buttons.

The static is minimal; it just slightly attracts your arm hair if you put your arm close, but the pages don't stick together or make any staticky crackling sound when you flip through them.  Also the components will always be in their paper or plastic tape within the sleeve.

Could this type of static hurt any of the components I listed (especially the MOSFETs or ICs)?  I've learned not to assume things, so I figured I'd ask before I fill this thing with hundred of components.  I know I could get a binder tailor-made for SMD stuff, but I just couldn't find exactly what I was looking for in that field.

Comment: Yes, very possibly.

Comment: The Q=CV charge between the leads is small compared to your body discharging to the part to one pin while coupled to another pin to the sheet. So less than handing off to another person with 3kV to 100 pF finger . SOME FETs blow their gates just looking at them sideways. (lol) FET buffers in TEK probes whereas CMOS has reasonable protection. An antistatic baggy is better with a ziplock

Comment: Yes, don't store them this way unless you have ESD sleeves.

Answer (score 4):

If you can discern the static charge, it's too much to be safe for chips.

If you're buying chips from a reputable source they're already coming to you in anti-static bags -- just leave them in.

Any passive, non-semiconductor component (i.e. caps, coils & resistors) should be fine with a bit of static electricity.

Comment: @Ronan You should read up on how anti-static materials work. You would then know that rubber washers wouldn't matter. What would matter is the hole punching itself. There are several classes of anti-static materials. For the most effective class, static-dissipative (looks like metalized foil bags), the bags being sealed properly matters and hole punching circumvents this if you the hole penetrates the inside surface of the bag. You need that Faraday cage.

Comment: Some semiconductor components can tolerate static. I've never seen a diode or JFET fail due to static, and certainly not a photoresistor (which is technically a semiconductor, just not usually thought of as one--and now not usually used at all, anyway).

Comment: True.  But putting something impervious to static in an anti-static bag won't hurt it at all, while putting something sensitive in a staticy back will.  So I suggested a sweeping rule.

Answer (score 2):

Everything that has a chip or on a board should be kept away.  Most chips can be damaged with as little as 5kV  and that is way less than what we can feel.   https://www.electronics-notes.com/articles/constructional_techniques/electrostatic-discharge/esd-basics.php

Comment: thanks for the answer and the link!

Answer (score 1):

ESD these days is an issue and there are some *inside* parts that are sensitive to even less than 20V. Usually component are manufactured to handle 2kV discharges, that means you need to control the environment to be under 500V (it's a probabilistic thing, JEDEC has the standards explaining in detail).

As for the plastic, the rule of thumb is as follow: if it's not explicitly conductive (i.e. metal) and it's not marked as ESD safe, it *is not* ESD safe (easy!).

I could rant for the differences between conducting/dissipating/shielding but for an operational standpoint it doesn't matter. The target for an ESD safe area is to have *everything* bonded to the ground with less than 8 megaohms.

Also: be aware that ESD can do subtle or latent damage, for example amplifiers go out of spec or component life severely shortened.